# Parsing results in java

Tags: java, regex, string-parsing

I have a string coming to me from another process in the format:

```
{{"data1""data2"}{"column1""column2""column3"}}
```

There could be any number of columns or data between the brackets in double quotes. I need to put each data point into a list and each column into another list.

I'm parsing it using java...  Having some trouble with regex because of the unknown number of data and columns.  Is there possibly a library or something else I could use?

Hope this makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if Regex is the best solution. I would use [String.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29).

```
int midIndex = myString.indexOf("}{");
String[] datas = myString.substring(2, midIndex).split("\"");
String[] columns = myString.substring(midIndex+2, myString.length()-2).split("\"");
```

The above will include some empty strings in the arrays but it is trivial to exclude the empty strings.

If you used Guava's [Splitter](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html) you could do:

```
Splitter mySplitter = Splitter.on("\")
   .trimResults()
   .omitEmptyStrings();

 Iterable<String> datas = mySplitter.split(myString.substring(2, midIndex));
 Iterable<String> columns = mySplitter.split(myString.substring(
                                    midIndex+2, myString.length()-2));
```

Comment: Thanks! I am looking into something similar with counting the number of brackets and quotes to determine that the format is correct, then splitting based on the number of quotes.  It doesnt need to be beautiful, so this should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

[ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) is often recommended as a parser solution (analogous to Lex/Yacc but in the Java world), but if the data format is trivial (e.g. no braces in yourdata/column elements) I would perhaps use a regexp to extract the inner data entities, and the inner column entities (i.e. the data inbetween the braces) and the split further, perhaps using another regexp.

Two distinct regexps (or one regexp and one subsequent string-splitting operation) would likely be *much* simpler than one catch-all regexp.

Comment: I've messed around with a few things and i think splitting it into two bracketed groups first is essential since there will likely be an uneven number of elements between each of the two bracket sets...  Thanks for the advice.